# enable text selection javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension, I want to enable text selection. When I execute this code in the chrome console, I was able to enable text.

```
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return true");
```

when I put the code on the document ready event, nothing happen.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    document.onselectstart=new Function ("return true");
});
```

Where should I put this line of code to make it work ?

Comment: I assume that you're trying on a website which is blocking text selection? If so I would start by looking what they do, and circumvent it. Perhaps their onselectstart hook is applied after yours?

Comment: yes that could be, Is there a way I can apply my hook after their hook ?

Comment: It's always difficult, but first of all find where they hook it and see if there's any obvious way to execute after it. For example you could hook their function, just remember to store original function and call it. In absolute worst case, hook an event you know will be executed after theirs or use timed/delayed execution (timeout)

Comment: I tried something like that, 
  `setTimeout(function(){
            document.onselectstart=new Function ("return true");
            alert('code executed !');
        }, 5000);` it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out, the event is not triggered ( I don't know why )

By adding the script dynamically it works

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = "document.onselectstart = function(){return true;};";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your problem is in implicit use of `eval`: you are making a function out of a string.

This [does not work with the default Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSEval) for extensions, but works in the console because those restrictions don't apply.

While you can override the CSP with `unsafe-eval`, try using anonymous functions instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    document.onselectstart = function(){return true;};
});
```

Comment: Interesting Information but unfortunately, it didn't work :( I edited the code and put it at many places and nothing happens. I put the code in content script file.

Comment: It seems the event is not triggered at all, I tried
    `document.onselectstart = function(){console.log('triggered!');return true;};`

Nothing showed at the console when I try to select, while I execute this code in console, I can show the in console "triggered!"